# Delete from denormalized table by id?

Tags: cassandra, cql

I'm trying to delete from records from cassandra using only part of the primary key, this is because I'm trying to delete all videos for certain tags for a given video, however I no longer have the original tags

Schema

Original Killr Video Table

```
CREATE TABLE videos (
   videoid uuid,
   userid uuid,
   name varchar,
   description varchar,
   location text,
   location_type int,
   preview_thumbnails map<text,text>,
   tags set<varchar>,
   metadata set <frozen<video_metadata>>,
   added_date timestamp,
   PRIMARY KEY (videoid)
);
```

Denormalized Video by tag

```
CREATE TABLE videos_by_tag (
   tag text,
   videoid uuid,
   added_date timestamp,
   name text,
   preview_image_location text,
   tagged_date timestamp,
   PRIMARY KEY (tag, videoid)
);
```

I tried

```
DELETE FROM videos_by_tag WHERE videoid='SOMEUUID';
```

but cassandra complaints that I'm missing the tag part of the PK, I know this however how could I ever delete records from this sort of denormalized table if I no longer know the full PK ?

Comment: Which cassandra version are you using ?

Comment: @GuillaumeS I'm using Cassandra 3.0.7

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can use materialized view.

In this case, you have a master table like :

```
CREATE TABLE videos (
    tag text,
    videoid uuid,
    added_date timestamp,
    name text,
    preview_image_location text,
    tagged_date timestamp,
    PRIMARY KEY (videoid)
);
```

You are able to delete with yours delete statement :

```
DELETE FROM videos WHERE videoid='SOMEUUID';
```

If you want to read data with others criteria , create materialized view :

```
CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW 
AS
SELECT *
FROM videos_by_tags
WHERE videoid IS NOT NULL
    AND tag IS NOT NULL
PRIMARY KEY (tag, videoid);
```

In this case if you insert, update or delete data in master table (videos).
Associated materialized view will be affected too. So wirte operations must be perform on one table and read on many tables.

Comment: I think this is a great idea, however I have multiple tags per video which makes the materialized view sort of complicated

Comment: Ok. So you can modify partition key in table 'videos' to include tag as clustering column, and set all other column in table videos static. With this structure you can add a video with a tag an it's informations and with static columns , you can just add an another tag to a video without specify other properties. But be careful, static columns cannot be add in materialized view. Specify columns videoid and tag in your view instead of *

Answer (score 1):

When I first created that schema, I was thinking in terms of managing records via application logic. By that, using application workflows to manage the data stored in the database. When you upload a new video, the videos table will get a record and so will videos_by_user and videos_by_tag. When updating, again all three may need to be updated.

In the case of delete, I would expect the application to present the user with a "Delete video?" option. Once that action is taken, the video_id is known and you can use it to delete from any index table. That's following a application workflow data model. Same with tags. If you delete a tag, update videos and videos_by_tag. Preferably with a batch statement to ensure both updates happen.

If you have orphan records of previously deleted videos, then my advice would be to use something like a Spark job to clean things up. Even with a relational DB that would take a fairly interesting sub-query to find all records in tags that have video_ids that don't have a parent record.